# Help finding a Basis for a subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

I have this assignment in which I'm asked to find a basis of the following subspace:

$$H=\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}0\\7\\7\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\3\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$$

As far as I'm concerned, a basis of a subspace is a set of vectors that spans the subspace and is linearly independent.

In this example the subspace is spanned by the set $\{(0, 7 ,7), (0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 3) \}$, but this set isn't linearly independent, so basically I don't know what else to do.

I probably have a wrong concept of what or how to get a basis of a subspace so please someone help.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  If you take away one vector, are the other two linearly independent?

Comment: Prove that they *are* linearly independent, and prove moreover that they still span $H.$

Comment: May i ask How did you come to know they arent linear independent?…same test you can apply on any 2 of them..

Comment: @J.W.Tanner If I take the third one the (0, 7, 7) and (0, 1, 2) are linearly independent if I'm not wrong

Comment: @санкетмхаске For the 3x3 matrix i just calculated the determinant. If it equals 0 then it's linearly dependent.

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry English is not my first language. Are you saying the three of them are linearly independent? To check it I just calculated the determinant of a Matrix. If it's 0 then it's linearly dependent. And it was 0.

Comment: Also thank you to whoever corrected the question. I didn't know how these concepts were in English so I tried to translate them but I used them were wrong.

Comment: @AnneBauval oh okay sorry

Comment: @Arksuga are you familiar with row echelon form of matrices?

Comment: @санкетмхаске I think so yeah

Comment: @санкетмхаске It's just i preferred not to use it since the 3 vector have a 0 as the first value, so i don't know if it's possible to use it in this example. Nevermind i was talking about another method sorry

Comment: Thank you I already solved it with all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

**Claim:** Suppose the set $\{ v_i \} = \{ v_1, ..., v_n \}$ is linearly dependent; i.e., there exists some nontrivial solution to $\alpha_1 v_1 + ... + \alpha_n v_n = 0$. In particular, let $\alpha_m \ne 0$ in this solution. Then we may write

$$v_m = -\sum_{i \ne m} \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_m} v_i$$

In other words, $v_m$ is a linear combination of $\{ v_i \}_{i \ne m}$. Then ${\rm Span} \{ v_i \} = {\rm Span} \{ v_i \}_{i \ne m}$.

**Proof:** That ${\rm Span} \{ v_i \}_{i \ne m} \subseteq {\rm Span} \{ v_i \}$ is straightforward; it can be seen directly from the fact that $\{ v_i \}_{i \ne m} \subseteq \{ v_i \}$.

To show that ${\rm Span} \{ v_i \} \subseteq {\rm Span} \{ v_i \}_{i \ne m}$, take a vector $w \in {\rm Span} \{ v_i \}$. By definition, there exists some $\beta_1, ..., \beta_n$ such that $w = \beta_1 v_1 + ... + \beta_n v_n = \beta_m v_m + \sum_{i \ne m} \beta_i v_i$. Now, we know that $v_m = -\sum_{i \ne m} \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_m} v_i$, where $\alpha_m \ne 0$. So, $w = \sum_{i \ne m} \left( \beta_i - \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_m} \beta_m \right) v_i$, showing that $w \in {\rm Span} \{ v_i \}_{i \ne m}$.

**Takeaway:** Loosely speaking, removing a "dependent" vector does not change the span of a set of vectors. You can repeat the process of removing dependent vectors until you have a linearly independent set, which will naturally be a basis for the original span.

Comment: Thank you I now solved it, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

We know that $H$ is the space spanned by the $3$ vectors you provided
$$H=\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}0\\7\\7\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\3\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle=\langle v_1,v_2,v_3\rangle\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$$

Pretty clearly we know that $v_1, v_3$ are linearly independent as $v_3$ has no entry in the second row. The same argument can be made $v_2,v_3$ are independent. The next question is, can we remove one of these and still span the same subspace?

In order to this, lets say we want to remove $v_1$, can we find a $c_1, c_2$ such that

$$
c_1v_2 + c_2v_3 = v_1
$$
and if that is true (hint, it is) then we can remove it from the basis without changing the subspace. This is because anything that we create using $v_1$ can be made using $v_2,v_3$ which means its needless to have!

Since this is homework I won't calculate the $c_1,c_2$ for you but it shouldn't be too tough

Comment: Oh thank you how come I didn't think of this. I tried to do that but for some reason I was only multiplying one of the vector, not the two of them. I don't know if you will understand me but thank you, now i do understand it perfectly.